# Code doesn't execute face detection and recognition tasks

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a computer vision project and here's how my code should work:
In the while loop the code should run a function that returns a string for the first 5 frames. And if the function returns an output that I am looking for then it should go ahead and run the rest of the code. The remaining code involves two functions which mainly performs face detection and recognition tasks. I want these tasks to be performed for 1 or 2 frames per second only. The problem is my code doesn't execute the detection and recognition part.

```
frame_id = 0
        while True:
            frame = video_capture.read()
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)    #resize frame (optional)
            height, width = frame.shape[:2]
            frame_id += 1
            # Selecting 5 frames per second to
            
            flag = False
            if frame_id <= 5:
                event = Bodyevent(frame)
                if event is None:
                    continue
                if "1" in  event or "2" in event:
                    cv2.putText(frame, "DETECTED", (100, height - 20),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, 
                                (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    flag = True
            
           
            if flag == True:
                # Now run the tasks 
                if frame_id % 6 == 0:
                    print("frame: ", frame_id)
                    # detect object #1
                    detect(frame)               
                    
                    find_results = []
                    
                    if frame.ndim == 2:
                        frame = facenet.to_rgb(frame)
                    frame = frame[:, :, 0:3]
                    bounding_boxes, _ = detect_face.detect_face(frame, minsize, pnet, rnet, onet, threshold, factor)
                    # detect number of faces and store in nrof_faces
                    nrof_faces = bounding_boxes.shape[0]
                    
                    
                    if nrof_faces > 0:
                        label = classify_face(frame)
                        # recognition task #
                    else:
                        print('Unable to align')
```

Comment: `if (c % timeF == 0):`, but `c` is not assigned a value anywhere in the code you show. Is it a constant maybe? Did you mean to use `curTime`? In any case, it is unlikely for that test to return true. You are better off checking the time since you last started doing face detection.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on why this code cannot return True?? I just want to use first few frames (5) to run a function and if it returns True then perform face detection and recognition. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Yes ```c``` is a constant but I have removed that from the code because it was just something that I was trying out. And as stated ```curTime``` was used for calculating fps. I just provided you with a shortest code possible rather that pasting the whole code but I have updated now to be more clear.

Comment: Step through your code, examining the values of `flag` and `frame_id`. `flag` is only true for the frame where you detect some event. This can only happen when `frame_id <= 5`. `frame_id` starts at 1, so anytime `flag` is true, `frame_id` must be between 1 and 5. If `flag` is true, you only do something if `frame_id % 6 == 0`. This test is only true if `frame_id` is 0, 6, 12, ... So it is impossible for both `flag` to be true, and this test to be true as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining in great detail. Any suggestion on what changes I should make to do what I want which is again just run a function for first few frames and if the flag is true it'll go for executing the later functions.

Comment: Write two independent loops, first `for frame_id in range(5)`, then a `while True` loop. I think this is what you want.